# Irrational equation problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I already asked the question whether it is necessary to check if after powering the sides of irrational equation the solutions satisfy the equation but nobody knew the answer. Now, consider this equation
$$(x+1)^\frac{1}{3}+(x-1)^\frac{1}{3}=(5x)^\frac{1}{3}$$

Taking the cubes of both sides I found the following solutions: $x=0$, $x=\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}$ 
or $x=-\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}$. For x=0 it is easy to check that it's a solution. However, for the other two roots it's not so easy. Can anyone propose a full solution to the problem?

Comment: I'm a bit worried about the use of fractional powers in anything as it is a multivalued function.  Perhaps if it were rewritten with $\sqrt[3]{~~}$ instead (the principle cube root).  Perhaps someone smarter than me can dispel or confirm the fear I have.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use the Binomial Theorem to get  $\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2^{4/3}}\right)^3 = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+1$ and $\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2^{4/3}}\right)^3 = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-1$.

After you show this, you have $\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+1\right)^{1/3} = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2^{4/3}}$ and $\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-1\right)^{1/3} = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2^{4/3}}$.

Comment: I understand what you mean but is it always necessary to substitute the numbers in the initial equation? The answer says that only 0 is root.

Comment: Then the answer given is wrong.  Because $\sqrt{5}/2$ satisfies the equation.  (With positive numbers, one can unambiguously take the $1/3$ power to mean the positicve real cube root.)